# How can I show my database values on a HTML-file without php?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql, psql

I want to show my different persons I have in my database on a HTML file so that I can see it in a Web page. I have no problems with connecting my HTML fiel with my server.js file!

I already tried to code an function which outputs the QUERY of the database

```js
const { Client } = require('pg');

const client = new Client({
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'castle',
    password: '123',
    user: 'king',
    port: 5432
})

const QUERY = `
select first_name, last_name, fav_color
from persons
where age >= 20;`

console.log('Connecting to db...');

client.connect()
    .then(() => client.query(QUERY))
    .then(result => {
        console.log('Received result..');
        result.rows.forEach(row => console.log(row));
    })
    .catch(err=> console.error(err))
    .finally(() => client.end())
```

I have received my requested persons in a Object:
`Object {first_name: "Mark", last_name: "Ruffalo", fav_color: "green"}`
...

Comment: You need server-side code.

Comment: What have you tried? What don't you understand?

Comment: I dont understand how i can show the query in a html file or web page. I tried to change the result.rows.forEach(row => console.log(row)); into a function but that doesnt worked.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/getting-started.html)? It is a Node.js ORM for SQL database. It is easy to set up and use.